# How to refresh only 2 column values from database onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one table, in that i have 2 columns one is files & and another permissions.

for all table rows i have refresh buttons.

What i need is when i click the refresh button it should only refresh the columns of the same row,where the refresh button is.

but now it is refreshing the particular row and particular column, but when i change the values in database and click refresh, the changed value is not getting updated...

here is my code:

Jquery Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buton").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().siblings(".b1").load(".b1");
            $(this).parent().siblings(".b2").load(".b2");
        });
    });      
</script>
```

jsp code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class = "b1"><s:property value="%{#u.files}" /></td>
        <td class = "b2"><s:property value="%{#u.perm}" /></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" id="buton"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I must be missing something, bu you have no button here. How is your click handler supposed to be attached to anything ?

Answer (score 2):

The `$(this)` in your button click function is the `<img>` element (which isn't closed by the way). The parent, which you call by `$(this).parent()` of that element is the `<a>` element, not the `<td>`. So you're searching for siblings of that `<a>` element instead of the `<td>` element.